# Mapping the complex right half plane to the interior of a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

I don't know how to approach this problem: Let $P$ be the complex plane; the function
$$z'(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
maps $P\rightarrow P$, where $z'$, $z$ are complex variables and ($a$, $b$, $c$, $d$) are complex constants. What is the function $z'(z)$ that maps the superior semi-plane defined by $\Re(z)>0$, to the interior of a circle of radius 1 defined by $|z'|<1$? What is the inverse of this function $z(z')$ (maps the interior of a circle of radius 1 to the superior semi-plane)?

I would appreciate any relevant hints to find the ($a$, $b$, $c$, $d$) needed for such a transformation (for example, I find that the condition $|z'|<1$ yields $|z|>|\frac{b-d}{c-a}|$).

Comment: What is superior semi plane? The complex upper half plane?

Comment: @See-WooLee my mistake I was referring to the complex right plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex number $z$ is in the upper half space iff its distance to $i$ is strictly smaller than its distance to $-i$, iff $\vert {z-i\over z+i} \vert <1$. Therefore

$h(z)={z-i\over z+i}$ does the job, as $ z\in \cal H  \iff \vert h(z) \vert <1 \iff h(z)\in D  $

You can replace $i$ by any complex number $z_0$ with positive imaginary part, and $h$ by $z-z_0\over z-{\bar z_0}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, the title of the question was incorrect, instead of $\Im(z)>0$, I was referring to $\Re(z)>0$. In any case your answer ($\Im(z)>0$) can be made more general by $z'(z)=\alpha\frac{z-z_0}{z-z^*_0}$ where $|\alpha|=1$ ($\Im(z_0)>0$ as before). If instead we consider $\Re(z)>0$, the solution is now (by rotation) $z'(z)=\alpha\frac{z+i z_0}{z+i z^*_0}$, with $|\alpha|=1$, and $\Im(z_0)>0$ as before.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to compute the inverse map first.  The map will map boundary to boundary, so it has to map some point on the unit circle to $\infty$  If we choose this point to be $1$ we need $c=-d$.  Then it has to map $-1$ to the real line so $\Im\left(\frac{-a+b}{-c+d}\right)= 0.$  Also $0$ is mapped to the upper half plane so $\Im\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)> 0$  It's easy to find $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy these conditions, and then to find the inverse map.

Comment: Thanks, it's very intuitive, although I feel it's not general enough since you are choosing specific points that correspond between a map and the other. I'm wondering is it necessary to map boundary to boundary (any general transformation)? for example if I tried to map the boundary of the semi-plane to the center of the circle, that wouldn't be a function anymore, but what if the map was to a neighborhood near the center?

Comment: A conformal mapping will always map the boundary to the boundary.  If you are looking for the most general mapping, just map an arbitrary  point to $\infty.$